# Can a Brownian Motion be scaled by a random time still be a brownian motion?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, brownian-bridge

I was reading the proof that if $\tau=\sup\{s\in [0,1]:B_{s}=0\}\wedge 1$. Then $\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau}}W_{\tau t}\bigg)_{t\in [0,1]}$ is a Standard Brownian Bridge in $[0,1]$ from [here](https://almostsuremath.com/2021/03/29/brownian-bridges/).

In the proof (Lemma 15 and Lemma 16), they are using that for a standard Brownian Motion $Y_{t}$ , we have that $(\sqrt{\tau}\cdot Y_{t/\tau})_{t\in [0,1]}$  is again a Standard Brownian Motion.

However, I have not encountered such a scaling by a Random Time before. $\tau$ is also not a stopping time.

> So my question is whether $(\sqrt{\tau}\cdot Y_{t/\tau})_{t\in [0,1]}$
> is a Brownian Motion or not and if the above is indeed true, then how
> should I go about proving this?

Firstly, I don't see how this is a Gaussian process. To be honest, I don't even see even for a fixed $t$, how is $\sqrt{\tau} Y_{t/\tau}$ has normal distribution. So I cannot go about computing the covariances. However, I can easily see that conditioned on $\tau$, we have that it is a Brownian Motion by usual scaling invariance.

Can anyone provide a proof or a reference or more details for this ?

Comment: What is wrong with relying on Lemma 16 from the ref. you shared?

Comment: @Math-fun In proving Lemma 16, the fact that $(\sqrt{\tau}\cdot Y_{t/\tau})_{t\in [0,1]}$  is a Standard Brownian Motion is used, where $Y$ is a Standard Brownian Motion also.

Comment: right, but then "measurability" is assumed which is essential for the validity of the arguments.

Comment: Lemma 16 assumes that for every $t>0$, the event $[\tau \ge t]$ depends only on $(X_s)_{s \ge t}$, and the prood uses heavily the independence of $Y$ and $\tau$, which follows from this assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to prove the following result:

> $\left(W_t\right)_{t\ge 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion independent from  the $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal F_{\tau}$ where $\tau$ is a random nonnegative variable, then $\left(\frac1{\sqrt{\tau}}W_{t\tau}\right)_{t\ge 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion.

Let $\tau_n = 2^{-n} \left(\left\lfloor 2^{n}\tau\right\rfloor + 1\right)$. It is clear that $\left[\tau_n = k2^{-n}\right]\in \mathcal F_{\tau}$ and

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[e^{iu \frac1{\sqrt{\tau_n}} W_{\tau_n t}}\right]
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb E\left[e^{iu\frac1{\sqrt{\tau_n}} W_{\tau_n t}}\mathbf 1_{\left\{\tau_n=k2^{-n}\right\}}\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[e^{iu\frac1{\sqrt{\tau_n}} W_{\tau_n t}}\mathbf 1_{\left\{\tau_n=k2^{-n}\right\}}\Big | \mathcal F_{\tau}\right]\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[e^{iu\frac1{\sqrt{k2^{-n}}} W_{k2^{-n}t}}\Big | \mathcal F_{\tau}\right]\mathbf 1_{\left\{\tau_n=k2^{-n}\right\}}\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-\frac12tu^2} \mathbb P\left[\tau_n = k2^{-n}\right]\\
&= e^{-\frac12tu^2}.
\end{align}

Since $\tau_n\to \tau$ a.s. then you have the result you are looking for.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this proof uses the independence lemma to compute the conditional expectation, which would require that $\tau$ is independent of $Y$.  Do you get the same result if $\tau$ is not independent of $Y$?

Comment: Sorry, it requires the measurability of what?  Regardless, could you please elaborate on the line $\mathbb{E}[e^{\sqrt{\tau} u (Y_{t/\tau} - Y_{s/\tau})}|\tau] = e^{-\frac 12 \tau u^2 \times \left(\frac t\tau - \frac s\tau \right)}$?  Or am I misunderstanding that proof, and the claim is only that they are equal in expectation?

Comment: Ah ofcourse. I had conditioned on $\tau$ but forgot that in the expression for the mgf or characteristic function, we would get $\sqrt{\tau}^{2}$ and it nicely cancels out. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late response but akin to user6247850's question, how are you saying $\mathbb{E}[e^{\sqrt{\tau} u (Y_{t/\tau} - Y_{s/\tau})}|\tau] = e^{-\frac 12 \tau u^2 \times \left(\frac t\tau - \frac s\tau \right)}$ ? And how does the measurability of $\tau$ help here? For all I know, $\tau$ is such that $\{\tau\geq t\}$ is measurable wrt the tail $\sigma(X_{s}:s\geq t)$. @Kroki

Comment: The independence of $Y$ and $\tau$ is actually important and used in the proof of Lemma 16. It follows from the assumption (forgotten in this post) that for every $t>0$, the event $[\tau \ge t]$ depends only on $(X_s)_{s \ge t}$.

Comment: As @user6247850 mentioned the independence of $Y$ and $\tau$ is crucial to this proof. The independence of them is assured by the result on $\tau$. I will update my answer to include that.

Comment: @Dovahkiin I edited my answer you can look at it now and you will have proof of what you are looking for.

Comment: @Kroki What is wrong with just using $W_{\tau t}/\sqrt{\tau}$ for a stopping time $\tau$ and then repeating your proof. I think this will prove what I am trying to show as I want to show that for $1/\tau$ (as in question), which is a stopping time, we have $W_{\tau t}/\sqrt{\tau}$ is an SBM where $W$ is an SBM . The proof you are using is by following how Strong Markov Property is proved. Also I don't think the scaling $\tau(1+t)$ really helps me as we do have at $t=0$ that we get $\tau$ but at $t=1$, we get $2\tau$ which seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: @Kroki The above is providing that $W$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$. i.e. in the post, they first consider $Y_{t}=\bar{X_{t+\overline{\tau}}}-\bar{X_\overline{{\tau}}}$ which is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$ and then they have said that $\sqrt{\tau}Y_{t/\tau}$ is an SBM. Thereafter, can I directly use your proof to conclude that $\sqrt{\tau}Y_{t/\tau}=W_{t\sqrt{\bar{\tau}}}/\sqrt{\bar{\tau}}$ is a Brownian motion?

Comment: I edited the answer to prove the general result.

Comment: 1. What is $\mathcal F_\tau$? Just $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\tau$? 2. How does this answer relate to the question?

Comment: Yes $\mathcal F_\tau$ is any $\sigma-$algebra that $\tau$ is mesurable inside it. 2. It is related to the question perfectly.

Comment: No it's not. $W_t$ does not

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. Can you please explain?